# make useEffect run before render is completed OR an alternative to use Effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have functions that I want to execute when state changes. But I don't want them to wait until render is completed, since it doesn't depend on the rendered DOM.

Is there a way to execute a function when certain dependencies change just like `useEffect`, but not wait until rendering is completed?

I was thinking to use `useMemo` or `useCallback`, but it seems not an ideal solution since it uses memory.

Is there a direct solution for this?

Comment: What's the issue with waiting for rendering to finish? The difference should be completely imperceptible, I don't see the point of running a couple of milliseconds sooner

Comment: UseEffect you should use

Comment: @CertainPerformance Because I don't want the DOM to flicker when consecutive changes are made with states, on which an HTML component depends.

Comment: For example, if a state called `name` components gets updated by call backs called by two consecutive changes of interdependent states, it will render with first `name` value, and render the final value again, until the state change chain stops.

Comment: *I was thinking to use useMemo or useCallback, but it seems not an ideal solution since it uses memory.* Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code that you want to execute may call state setters itself, which results in undesirable flickering, you can switch out `useEffect` for [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect), which runs after the DOM mutations from the render have occurred, but before the browser has repainted the screen. As a result, if any state setters get called, and the component renders again, the user won't see the component rendering twice, because the updates all occur before the screen repainting (except for the very last one).

`useLayoutEffect` has the exact same function signature as `useEffect`, so making the changes should be quite trivial.

Comment: Is the only difference that both run after render is completed where `useEffect` runs after screen repaint and `useLayoutEffect` runs before screen repaint?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: can multiple renders take place before screen redraw? meaning, If it triggeres re-render, does the new re-render occur before the current redraw is done? If not, how can consecutive state based `useLayoutEffect`  calls be all run before a single screen redraw?

Comment: Yes, if a state setter is called inside a `useLayoutEffect` callback, the new re-render that state setter triggered will mutate the DOM before control is yielded back to the browser to repaint the screen.

Comment: That said, it's a *tiny* bit smelly to have this many consecutive state setter calls for it to be a UI problem. Consider if there's any way you could change the logic around so that you call all the necessary state setters *once*, perhaps after a recursive state calculation of some sort (that doesn't involve re-renders).

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that. How about for performance improvement ? if I want to avoid waiting rerenders in between consecutive state changes? is there a way to bypass `useEffect` or such render-waiting hooks? I only want their dependency checking feature